# Why is my query so much slower with a `security_barrier` view, even without row-level policy?

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security

I am developing an application where I want to make use of the builtin row-level security in Postgresql. To make sure my views also respect it, I enabled the `security_barrier` and `security_invoker` option on my views. This made one particular query take more than 20 seconds whereas before it executed in milliseconds.

### Minimal example

```sql
-- Two simple tables
CREATE TABLE foo (
    name varchar(20),
    id uuid
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS foo_idx ON foo (name);

CREATE TABLE bar (
    id uuid primary key,
    some_data text  -- needed to make sequential scans actually slow
);

-- Generate some data
INSERT INTO bar (id, some_data)
SELECT gen_random_uuid(), repeat(md5(random()::text) || md5(random()::text), 10)
FROM generate_series(1, 100000);

INSERT INTO foo (name, id)
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 5), bar.id FROM bar;

-- Create the problematic view
CREATE VIEW bar_protected WITH (security_barrier) AS (
    SELECT * FROM bar
);
```

The slow query: `SELECT * FROM foo INNER JOIN bar_protected ON bar_protected.id = foo.id WHERE foo.name LIKE 'ab%' LIMIT 10`

The equivalent but fast query: `SELECT * FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ON bar.id = foo.id WHERE foo.name LIKE 'ab%' LIMIT 10`

[Try it out on db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m3BH47DTMvKQrcgDux8agP/1) Execution of the slow query is usually >100ms, whereas the fast query takes <10ms.

### Analysis

I also tried it locally and looked at the execution plans, and it seems the slow query (on the left) uses a sequential scan on `bar` taking a lot of time. I'm not sure how to avoid that.

[image: pg-admin view of EXPLAIN ANALYZE]

Note: I'm running Postgresql 15.4 (and db-fiddle claims to run 15 as well).

Comment: The problem is that the security barrier prevents the use of the index, as it requires the RLS policy filter to be evaluated *before* the `LIKE`. Otherwise, errors might leak data - this depends on the properties of the `~~` operator.

Comment: The only workaround I know is to not use `security_invoker` but rather define the view so that it has the policy conditions built-in. Whether it's safe to circumvent the security barrier I cannot tell…

Comment: @Bergi Huh? There is no row level security at play anywhere. Any why would the `LIKE` operator on `foo` have any impact on whether an index scan on `bar` can be used or not? And `security_invoker` isn't used at all. Perhaps you are on to something, but you'd have to explain it better.

Comment: This is quite mysterious to me. The equality operator on `uuid` is leakproof, so an index scan on bar is no problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh right I had not looked closely at the example. I just saw "*I want to make use of the builtin row-level security in Postgresql.*" and remembered having problematic query plans due to the leak-proofing of policies myself. Indeed, the case of the `VIEW bar_protected WITH (security_barrier)` is mysterious.